# Ruby: exceptions from popen vs popen3

Tags: ruby, popen3

I'd like to know how to catch exceptions from `Open3.popen3` on Ruby.

```rb
require "open3"
begin
  Open3.popen3("./somebinary") {|i,o,e,t|
#  IO.popen("./somebinary") {|i|
    $stderr.puts "popen"
    i.puts "some string"
  }
rescue StandardError => e
  $stderr.puts e.message
  $stderr.puts e.backtrace.inspect
  $stderr.puts "error"
  exit(1)
end
```

The problem is that the binary executable is of a wrong architecture and doesn't run on the local machine.  When invoked from the command line, like so `./somebinary`, you see the error message.

With `popen`, the error is caught by the rescue clause, but not with `popen3`.

If the `rescue` clause didn't have `StandardError => e`, the clause is entered, but you can't know the reason for the error because all you see is the message "error" from `$stderr.puts "error"`.  With `popen3`, the stderr from the command line vanishes!

I'm using ruby 3.0.1p64 on macOS 11.3.1 .

**A complete example**

```sh
~/tmp $ ./somebinary
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/furue/tmp/./somebinary
  Reason: image not found
fish: Job 1, './somebinary' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
~/tmp [134] $ ruby --version
ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [arm64-darwin20]
~/tmp $ cat try-popen3.rb
require "open3"
begin
  Open3.popen3("./somebinary") {|i,o,e,t|
    $stderr.puts "in popen . . . "
    i.puts "some string"
  }
rescue
  $stderr.puts "error in rescue . . . "
  exit(1)
end
~/tmp $ ruby try-popen3.rb
in popen . . .
~/tmp $ cat try-popen3-standarderror.rb
require "open3"
begin
  Open3.popen3("./somebinary") {|i,o,e,t|
    $stderr.puts "in popen . . . "
    i.puts "some string"
  }
rescue StandardError => e
  $stderr.puts e.message
  $stderr.puts e.backtrace.inspect
  $stderr.puts "error in rescue . . . "
  exit(1)
end
~/tmp $ ruby try-popen3-standarderror.rb
in popen . . .
~/tmp $ cat try-popen.rb
require "open3"
begin
  IO.popen("./somebinary") {|i|
    $stderr.puts "in popen . . . "
    i.puts "some string"
  }
rescue
  $stderr.puts "error in rescue . . . "
  exit(1)
end
~/tmp $ ruby try-popen.rb
in popen . . .
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/furue/tmp/./somebinary
  Reason: image not found
error in rescue . . .
~/tmp [1] $ cat try-popen-standarderror.rb
require "open3"
begin
  IO.popen("./somebinary") {|i|
    $stderr.puts "in popen . . . "
    i.puts "some string"
  }
rescue StandardError => e
  $stderr.puts e.message
  $stderr.puts e.backtrace.inspect
  $stderr.puts "error in rescue . . . "
  exit(1)
end
~/tmp $ ruby try-popen-standarderror.rb
in popen . . .
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/furue/tmp/./somebinary
  Reason: image not found
not opened for writing
["try-popen-standarderror.rb:5:in `write'", "try-popen-standarderror.rb:5:in `puts'", "try-popen-standarderror.rb:5:in `block in <main>'", "try-popen-standarderror.rb:3:in `popen'", "try-popen-standarderror.rb:3:in `<main>'"]
error in rescue . . .
~/tmp [1] $
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error message from executing `./somebinary` comes from your `rescue` block? It seems more likely that the binary writes to stderr itself, which is not captured by `IO.popen`. The `rescue` block is probably entered because `i.puts` raises an `IOError`.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks!  You are likely to be correct, but my question remains. With popen3, the rescue block is **not** entered even if `i.puts` raises an error.